# Is cryolipolisis effective as a fat reduction method?

Tags: medical-science, weight-loss

[Cryolipolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryolipolysis) is a non-surgical process to remove subcutaneous fat, using controlled cooling, as an alternative to liposuction.

Is a significant amount of fat destroyed by one treatment of cryolipolysis? Is it an effective alternative to liposuction?

Comment: Can someone help by putting a bounty here? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is effective and safe.

Both preclinical and clinical studies have established the safety and efficacy of cryolipolysis for noninvasive body contouring <sup>[1]</sup>.

Cryolipolysis has demonstrated efficacy in both human and animal studies. Histology findings also confirm the selective reduction of fat in both humans and animals, with evidence of a gradual thinning of the fat layer over a period of two to four months. Importantly, cryolipolysis has not produced any significant adverse side effects in studies to date and any noted effects have been minor and temporary <sup>[2]</sup>.

Erythema of the skin, bruising, and temporary numbness at the treatment site are commonly observed following treatment with the device, though these effects largely resolve in approximately 1 week. To date, there have been no reports of scarring, ulceration, or alterations in blood lipid or liver function profiles <sup>[3]</sup>.

Although the mechanism of action for cryolipolysis is not yet completely understood, the efficacy and safety of this non-invasive procedure for fat layer reduction has been demonstrated in the studies available to data. Further studies willl assist in identifying the mechanism and elucidate the full potential of this technology to perform safe, non-invasive fat reduction for areas of local fat accumulation <sup>[2]</sup>.

---

References:

1. Jalian HR, Avram MM. [*Cryolipolysis: a historical perspective and current clinical practice.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24049927) Semin Cutan Med Surg. 2013 Mar;32(1):31-4.
2. Avram MM, Harry RS. [*Cryolipolysis for subcutaneous fat layer reduction.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20014262) Lasers Surg Med. 2009 Dec;41(10):703-8. doi: 10.1002/lsm.20864.
3. Nelson AA, Wasserman D, Avram MM. [*Cryolipolysis for reduction of excess adipose tissue.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20123423) Semin Cutan Med Surg. 2009 Dec;28(4):244-9. doi: 10.1016/j.sder.2009.11.004.

Comment: However I had a glance to that paper and they lack of quantitative analysis. And FDA has not yet approved it as a fat-loss method. My impression, after a first glance at them, is that the amount of fat lost is very small. I'm not sure it can be a valid alternative to Lyposucition or BodyTite