# Is BodyTite effective at tightening the skin during liposuction?

Tags: medical-science, weight-loss

[BodyTite](http://wikibin.org/articles/bodytite.html) or Radio Frequency Assisted Liposuction (RFAL) is a form of liposuction helped by radio frequency:

> involves heating the skin by the RF current which flows from the
>   internal to the external electrode placed on the skin above the
>   internal electrode.

The claimed benefits include that it is painless, safer, has a faster recovery, less tissue trauma, less coagulation of blood vessels, and that:

> the maximum skin contraction that is achieved through conventional liposuction techniques can be increased by up to 60%.

Looseness of the skin after a liposuction leads to the need for an [abdominoplasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominoplasty). Does the use of BodyTite avoid this need?

Comment: If you skim through the different Skeptics questions, you will find that there the consensus is that radio frequencies will not affect the human body in a measurable way. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones